# windows control left/right arrow to end of line

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

On my mac, on any line of text (in any sot, if I press `command + arrow left/right`, the cursor jumps to the beginning or end of the line, and if I press `option + arrow left/right`, the cursor jumps to the previous or next word.

On Windows 10, `Ctrl+ arrow left/right` jumps to the previous or next word (the equivalent of mac's `option + arrow left/right`). Is there a way to change the windows 10 shortcuts such that `Ctrl+ arrow left/right` jump to the beginning or end of the line (the equivalent of mac's `command + arrow left/right`), and `Alt+ arrow left/right` will jump to the previous or next word?

Comment: Programs that use inbuilt edit controls (or derivatives eg combo listbox) or richedit controls this is built in to the control although the program can override. In other programs it depends on the program. The IBM's Common User Access standard specifies these keys. You can swap control and alt key though.

Comment: In windows, the Home and End keys on the keyboard work as you expect Ctrl+ arrow to work. you can try mapping a key/key combo to Home and End if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

To following AutoHotkey script will:

- Replaces <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left/right</kbd> by
  <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd>
  to go to the beginning/end of the line
- Replaces <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>left/right</kbd> by
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left/right</kbd>
  to skip words left or right

The script is as follows:

```
$^left::Send, {home}
$^right::Send, {end}
$!left::Send, ^{left}
$!right::Send, ^{right}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

(However, in my opinion, learning and using the Windows
standard hotkeys is more productive in the long run than
forcing Windows to emulate the Mac.)

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Thank you! Amazing solution. On a side note, why do you think using the Windows standard hotkeys would be more productive in the long run? Did you find it a little inconvenient pressing `home` and `end` above the arrow keys?

Comment: *Common User Access (CUA) is a standard for user interfaces to operating systems and computer programs. It was developed by IBM and first published in 1987 as part of their Systems Application Architecture. Used originally in the MVS/ESA, VM/CMS, OS/400, OS/2 and Microsoft Windows operating systems, parts of the CUA standard are now implemented in programs for other operating systems, including variants of Unix. It is also used by Java AWT and Swing.*  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access#Description. I've used it in VM/CMS, OS/2, and MSDos / Windows.

Comment: I find it inconvenient when a system doesn't have Home/End, or uses Function keys for them. I rarely use the ctrl+arrow options in part because any key combo is less convenient than a single keypress.

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks for this comment. I'm coming from a Mac and at first found what you were saying to seem strange (it's so much closer to my fingers to find the ctrl and alt buttons). However, after playing with the Home/End keys for a few seconds, as well as noting their proximity (on my keyboard) to the arrows, page up, page down, delete, and insert keys (as well as other special keys), it really does seem much more productive than using the macOS and Linux shortcuts.